# Ruby on Rails - How to do custom query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 tables with millions of records:

First table is `Subscription` and second table is `Message`.

In `Subscription` table, I have 3 indexes:

- `subscription_id`
- `msisdn`
- `reporting_id`

However, in `Message` table, I only have 2 indexes:

- `message_id`
- `reporting_id`

*I have `msisdn` in `Message` table but **it is not indexed.***

So, I have a dashboard UI that let me search for `Message`.

I want to search `Message` using `msisdn` but since `msisdn` is not indexed, the query is taking forever!

but I want to put the idea of **"Indexing `msisdn` in `Message` table"** as plan B.

So my Plan A is(which is where I need help for):

Since both table has indexed `reporting_id`, I want to search for `Message` using `subscription.msisdn` in the dashboard, and then from there, I want to use the `subscription.reporting_id` and list all the `Message` with that `subscription.reporting_id`.

Something like `subscription.reporting_id = message.reporting_id`.

I have the `view`, `controller` and `model` for these 2 tables,

I tried doing this in both models

`has_many :message, foreign_key: :reporting_id` in `Subscription.rb`

and

`belongs_to :subscription` in `Message.rb`

but it didn't work.

In my `view`, the search_field for `MSISDN` is currently search for record from `subscription.msisdn`

Does anyone knows how can I achieve that?

PS: I want to prevent from editing the table structure.

Comment: `has_many` relationships need to be pluralized, ie `has_many :messages`.

Comment: @MikeHeft, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

In my `Message.rb`, I did:

```
belongs_to :subscription, foreign_key: :reporting_id, primary_key: :reporting_id
```

and it generated this query

```
SELECT  `subscription`.* FROM `subscription` WHERE `subscription`.`reporting_id` = '1eaa7a61fe635005c81df347b1a7c401' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to establish a `has_many :messages` association in the Subscription class, you'll need to specify the primary_key.

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: "reporting_id", primary_key: "reporting_id"
end
```

With this, the SQL generated will look like this:

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."reporting_id" = $1  [["reporting_id", "#{reporting_id}"]]
```

The primary_key ensures the `reporting_id` value of the `Subscription` model is used, else it will default to the id column.

However, rather than establishing this association which doesn't seem exactly normalized(atleast [3NF](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php)), you can just have a query to find all messages using the msisdn and reporting_id. Something like this should still be effective:

```
Message.
 joins("INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.reporting_id = messages.reporting_id").
 merge(Subscription.where(msisdn: "#{value}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :D, I tried both Kvr Ramya and your suggestion but it didn't work for me. But I found the solution based on you guy's code. I wrote `belongs_to :subscription, foreign_key: "reporting_id", primary_key: "reporting_id"` in `Message.rb` instead.

Answer (score 1):

have to add primary key as well
`has_many :message, foreign_key: :reporting_id, primary_key: :reporting_id` in `Subscription.rb`

Comment: Thanks for you answer :D, I found the fix!